# Free SQLite GUI tool?

Tags: mysql, ios, xcode, sqlite

Is there any Free SQLite GUI tool?

something like Workbench for MySQL?

I've been looking for something like that every tool I found is paid and very complex features...

I just want simple stuff like, creating tables, columns, run queries(insert,update,delete, select)

thanks all

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are good open source GUI SQLite database managers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507506/what-are-good-open-source-gui-sqlite-database-managers)

Comment: have you try on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507506/what-are-good-open-source-gui-sqlite-database-managers)?

Comment: see these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507506/what-are-good-open-source-gui-sqlite-database-managers

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835069/which-sqlite-administration-console-do-you-recommend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a nice free one that works with Firefox ... https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/

Thanks
:)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest tool I've seen is the Firefox add-on "SQLite Manager".  Allows you to browse your sqlite database, create tables and indexes, execute sql queries, export your data, etc.  Easy to use.  You run it from the Firefox Tools menu and connect to any sqlite database file on your computer.   Will not do fancy stuff like diagram your DB schema -- but if you want something simple, this is it.

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla plugin is best and neat for sqllite.
Please note one limitation though while using to open the file directly under the bundle is that it gets locked and you need to keep reopening  or stop the app and refresh

Answer (score 0):

Try using [SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/).